# Floating div in the background

Tags: css, html

Tried to make a floating div, with a -1 z-index to be in the background all the time, but when I make it's position absolute, then it disappears. Also want to place it in the middle with y-repeat image.

```
.perchament{
    position:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    background: url("image_assets/parchment.png") repeat-y;
    margin-top:25px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Add a width to your div.

Comment: Have you considered using a background instead of a floating background div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It disappears because there is no content in it and no width specified.

Add this to your CSS:

```
left: 50%;
width: 100px;
margin-left: -50px;
```

The width needs to be set and the left margin is always half of that.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XJp8u/)

As others have said, why not just do a background image on the body?

```
body {
    background: url("image_assets/parchment.png") center repeat-y;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you'll need to add a width to your div (since it's absolutely positioned).

However, what's wrong with a `background` rule on the `body` element or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioning elements should us "top" and other such positioning controls instead of margin etc and set a width and height.

```
    .perchament{
        position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
width: 500px;
        margin:0 auto;
        height:100%;
        background: url("image_assets/parchment.png") repeat-y;
        margin-top:25px;
        z-index:-1;
    }
```

Does that help?

I'd also avoid using a minus z-index. Instead, you could set this item to z-index: 1 and then set the container above it (with everything else inside) to z-index: 2.

OR, if it's just a background image you want, you could simply put that onto the BODY tag of the document instead of a div. The BODY or HTML element is always the bottom of the stack.